# Check if order paid by card (Visa/MasterCard)

Tags: orders, payment, payment-methods

Please, explain, how can I check if order paid by (credit/debit) card?

I need to check if order paid by card in observer. I know only order id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the payment method title by order id

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); // your order entity_id

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); // increment id

echo $method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```

now the `$method` will return payment method title. So you can do your logic with this.

### Edit

As **@Marius** comment

```
$method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

The payment method code will not change for each store view. So better you could use method code.

Comment: I think it's better to check `$method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();` since the code never changes but the title can be changed for each store view. Other than that...good stuff.